# Compile .pxd file when using pyximport

Tags: python-3.x, cython

I'm augmenting a Python module with a `.pxd` file so that I can use it [pure Python mode](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html) for debugging (with pudb). So I have two files:

```
mymodule.py
mymodule.pxd
```

I'm using [pyximport](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-pyximport) in the standard way:

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
```

But `pyximport` doesn't seem to try to compile it. If I get rid of the `.pxd` file and rename my `.py` file to `.pyx` then it works. So, how can I use `pyximport` but still be able to run in pure Python mode? Ideally I'd like to be able to simply comment out the `pyximport` like to switch to pure python mode.

Answer (score 0):

try `pyximport.install(pyimport=True)`, you can see the full document of this function by type `pyximport.install?` in ipython if installed. Or check the source: https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/pyximport/pyximport.py

**WARNING:** any .py file imported after `pyximport.install(pyimport=True)` will be compiled, this may result in some errors, eg: __init__.py is compiled to an empty pyd, then the import will fail

`pyximport` is useful for some simple tests and can be very tricky for complex builds, it should be avoided in real projects.

Comment: Won't this compile _all_ `.py` files? I only want it to do it for a couple, not e.g. system libraries too.

Comment: Yes, It will! @z0r  Any .py module imported after `pyximport.install(pyimport=True)` will be compiled. I think `pyximport` is just useful for some simple tests, for more complex builds, a setup.py script will be more suitable.